# Extend Micronaut CustomJWTClaimsSetGenerator to provide all attributes

Tags: java, authentication, jwt, micronaut

I have the following two classes which provide the JWT authentication mechanisem.

**CustomDelegatingAuthenticationProvider**

```
@Singleton
@Replaces(value = DelegatingAuthenticationProvider.class)
public class CustomDelegatingAuthenticationProvider extends DelegatingAuthenticationProvider {
    /**
     * @param userFetcher        Fetches users from persistence
     * @param passwordEncoder    Collaborator which checks if a raw password matches an encoded password
     * @param authoritiesFetcher Fetches authorities for a particular user
     */
    public CustomDelegatingAuthenticationProvider(UserFetcher userFetcher, PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder, AuthoritiesFetcher authoritiesFetcher) {
        super(userFetcher, passwordEncoder, authoritiesFetcher);
    }

    @Override
    protected Publisher<AuthenticationResponse> createSuccessfulAuthenticationResponse(AuthenticationRequest authenticationRequest, UserState userState) {

        if (userState instanceof UserMember) {
            UserMember user = (UserMember) userState;
            return Flowable
                    .fromPublisher(authoritiesFetcher.findAuthoritiesByUsername(user.getUsername()))
                    .map(authorities -> new HDSUser(user.getUsername(), authorities, user.getId()));
        }
        return super.createSuccessfulAuthenticationResponse(authenticationRequest, userState);
    }
}
```

**CustomJWTClaimsSetGenerator**

```
@Singleton
@Replaces(value = JWTClaimsSetGenerator.class)
public class CustomJWTClaimsSetGenerator extends JWTClaimsSetGenerator {

    CustomJWTClaimsSetGenerator(TokenConfiguration tokenConfiguration, @Nullable JwtIdGenerator jwtIdGenerator, @Nullable ClaimsAudienceProvider claimsAudienceProvider) {
        super(tokenConfiguration, jwtIdGenerator, claimsAudienceProvider);
    }

    protected void populateWithUserDetails(JWTClaimsSet.Builder builder, UserDetails userDetails) {
        super.populateWithUserDetails(builder, userDetails);

        if (userDetails instanceof HDSUser) {
            builder.claim("userId", ((HDSUser) userDetails).getId());
        }
    }

}
```

The default response to the client looks like this:

[image]

My question. How can I extend the class to return all user attributes? Besides username I want to have the user id.

**UPDATE**

HDS user class which gathers the DB id

```
@CompileStatic
public class HDSUser  extends UserDetails {

    private long id;

    public HDSUser(String username, Collection<String> roles, long id) {
        super(username, roles);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a shot in the dark, but userDetails could possible not be `instanceof HDSUser`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extend the returned data you need to extend (implement custom) `TokenRenderer` as well as a custom version of the `AccessRefreshToken`.
Just as a simple example see the following code snipped which will extend the default access token payload with `userId` field.

First, create a custom `AccessRefreshToken` class with additional fields which are required.

```
@Introspected
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomAccessRefreshToken extends BearerAccessRefreshToken {
    
    // the new field which will be in the response
    private String userId;

    public CustomAccessRefreshToken(String username,
                                Collection<String> roles,
                                Integer expiresIn,
                                String accessToken,
                                String refreshToken,
                                String tokenType
    ) {
        super(username, roles, expiresIn, accessToken, refreshToken, tokenType);
    }
  
}
```

Next, we will need a `TokenRenderer` which will be used by the underlying subsystem to generate our custom token.

```
@Singleton
@Replaces(value = BearerTokenRenderer.class)
public class CustomTokenRenderer implements TokenRenderer {
    private static final String BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE = HttpHeaderValues.AUTHORIZATION_PREFIX_BEARER;

    @Override
    public AccessRefreshToken render(Integer expiresIn, String accessToken, @Nullable String refreshToken) {
    return new AccessRefreshToken(accessToken, refreshToken, BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE, expiresIn);
    }

    @Override
    public AccessRefreshToken render(Authentication authentication, Integer expiresIn, String accessToken, @Nullable String refreshToken) {
        CustomAccessRefreshToken token =  new CustomAccessRefreshToken(authentication.getName(), authentication.getRoles(), expiresIn, accessToken, refreshToken, BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE);
        // here just take the user data from Authentication object or access any other service
        token.setUserId("Some user id");
        return token;
    }
}
```

That's it )) Just implement `render()` method the way you want and add as many custom fields as needed.

The response from the given example will look like

```
{
    "username": "sherlock",
    "userId": "Some user id",
    "access_token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJzdWIiOiJzaGVybG9jayIsIm5iZiI6MTYzNjk5MTgzMSwicm9sZXMiOltdLCJpc3MiOiJtaWNyb25hdXRndWlkZSIsImV4cCI6MTYzNjk5NTQzMSwiaWF0IjoxNjM2OTkxODMxfQ.Cat1CTsUZkCj-OHGafiefNm1snPsALoaNw9y2xwF5Pw",
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 3600
}
```

If you are on the older version of the Micronaut v1.x the TokenRenderer will look like this.

```
@Singleton
@Replaces(value = BearerTokenRenderer.class)
public class CustomTokenRenderer implements TokenRenderer {
    private static final String BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE = HttpHeaderValues.AUTHORIZATION_PREFIX_BEARER;

    public AccessRefreshToken render(Integer expiresIn, String accessToken, String refreshToken) {
        return new AccessRefreshToken(accessToken, refreshToken, BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE, expiresIn);
    }

    public AccessRefreshToken render(UserDetails userDetails, Integer expiresIn, String accessToken, String refreshToken) {
        CustomAccessRefreshToken token =  new CustomAccessRefreshToken(userDetails.getUsername(), userDetails.getRoles(), expiresIn, accessToken, refreshToken, BEARER_TOKEN_TYPE);
        token.setUserId("Some user id, Some user id");
        return token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but how can I manage my endpoit to reach this classes?

Comment: No need to manage anything, the system is configured to reach them. If you are in the authentication: bearer mode and someone POSTs the correct username/password pair to /login endpoint the code will be executed.

Comment: ok i will try...I just have some issues with some annotations. Could you also add the imports?

Comment: I was using lombok, in case you do not use it just remove the `@Getter`
`@Setter` and manually implement getters and setters

Comment: CustomTokenRenderer requires two different render methods..?

Comment: Yes, just look into TokenRenderer for details

Comment: Check pictures inside my question for errors I am talking about.

Comment: Class 'CustomTokenRenderer' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'render(Integer, String, String)' in 'TokenRenderer'

Comment: Method does not override method from its superclass

Comment: My example is based on latest version of micronaut; just implement based in the version which you have

Comment: Please do not update my answer, and just share the Micornaut version which you have.

Comment: @Jacob just in case you still need it, I have added Micornaut v1 code

Comment: Works now. But still I cannot get the ID from the actual DB entry, it works only with a custom one....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239274/discussion-between-babl-and-jacob).